# How to create a OuterNotebook/welcome page in the Inno Setup uninstaller?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am using this code from the answer by Martin Prikryl to [Custom Inno Setup Uninstall page (not MsgBox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415457/custom-uninstall-page-not-msgbox/42550055#42550055).

How to modify the first page of this code to show a "Welcome"-like page on the `OuterNotebook` page (i.e. without the `MainPanel` header)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create the page as any other, except that its parent will be the `UninstallProgressForm.OuterNotebook`, not the `.InnerNotebook`.

Tricky part is not how to create the page, but how to implement the *Next*/*Back* buttons.

The *Next* button on the "welcome" page must change the page of the `OuterNotebook` from the "welcome" page to the `UninstallProgressForm.InnerPage`. And of course make sure the active page on the `.InnerNotebook` is the first normal/inner page.

Conversely, the *Back* button on the first normal/inner page must change the page of the `OuterNotebook` from the `UninstallProgressForm.InnerPage` to the "welcome" page.

So modifying my answer to the [Custom Inno Setup Uninstall page (not MsgBox)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7415457/850848#42550055) to cater for the above, you will get:

```
[Files]
Source: "compiler:WizModernImage-IS.bmp"; DestDir: {app}
```

```pascal
[Code]

var
  UninstallWelcomePage: TNewNotebookPage;
  UninstallFirstPage: TNewNotebookPage;
  UninstallSecondPage: TNewNotebookPage;
  UninstallBackButton: TNewButton;
  UninstallNextButton: TNewButton;

procedure UpdateUninstallWizard;
begin
  if UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage = UninstallFirstPage then
  begin
    UninstallProgressForm.PageNameLabel.Caption := 'First uninstall wizard page';
    UninstallProgressForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Caption :=
      'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.';
  end
    else
  if UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage = UninstallSecondPage then
  begin
    UninstallProgressForm.PageNameLabel.Caption := 'Second uninstall wizard page';
    UninstallProgressForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Caption :=
      'Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.';
  end;
  
  UninstallBackButton.Visible :=
    (UninstallProgressForm.OuterNotebook.ActivePage <> UninstallWelcomePage);

  if UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage <> UninstallSecondPage then
  begin
    UninstallNextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonNext);
    UninstallNextButton.ModalResult := mrNone;
  end
    else
  begin
    UninstallNextButton.Caption := 'Uninstall';
    // Make the "Uninstall" button break the ShowModal loop
    UninstallNextButton.ModalResult := mrOK;
  end;
end;  

procedure UninstallNextButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if UninstallProgressForm.OuterNotebook.ActivePage = UninstallWelcomePage then
  begin
    UninstallProgressForm.OuterNotebook.ActivePage :=
      UninstallProgressForm.InnerPage;
    UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage := UninstallFirstPage;
    UpdateUninstallWizard;
  end
    else
  begin
    if UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage <> UninstallSecondPage then
    begin
      if UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage = UninstallFirstPage then
      begin
        UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage := UninstallSecondPage;
      end;
      UpdateUninstallWizard;
    end
      else
    begin
      UninstallNextButton.Visible := False;
      UninstallBackButton.Visible := False;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure UninstallBackButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage = UninstallFirstPage then
  begin
    UninstallProgressForm.OuterNotebook.ActivePage := UninstallWelcomePage;
  end
    else
  if UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage = UninstallSecondPage then
  begin
    UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage := UninstallFirstPage;
  end;
  
  UpdateUninstallWizard;
end;

procedure InitializeUninstallProgressForm();
var
  PageText: TNewStaticText;
  UninstallWizardBitmapImage: TBitmapImage;
  PageNameLabel: string;
  PageDescriptionLabel: string;
  CancelButtonEnabled: Boolean;
  CancelButtonModalResult: Integer;
begin
  if not UninstallSilent then
  begin
    PageNameLabel := UninstallProgressForm.PageNameLabel.Caption;
    PageDescriptionLabel := UninstallProgressForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Caption;

    // Create the Welcome page and make it active
    UninstallWelcomePage := TNewNotebookPage.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
    UninstallWelcomePage.Notebook := UninstallProgressForm.OuterNotebook;
    UninstallWelcomePage.Parent := UninstallProgressForm.OuterNotebook;
    UninstallWelcomePage.Align := alClient;
    UninstallWelcomePage.Color := clWindow;
    
    UninstallWizardBitmapImage := TBitmapImage.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
    UninstallWizardBitmapImage.Parent := UninstallWelcomePage;
    UninstallWizardBitmapImage.Width := ScaleX(164);
    UninstallWizardBitmapImage.Height := ScaleX(314);
    UninstallWizardBitmapImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(
      ExpandConstant('{app}\WizModernImage-IS.bmp'));
    UninstallWizardBitmapImage.Center := True;
    UninstallWizardBitmapImage.Stretch := True;

    PageText := TNewStaticText.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
    PageText.Parent := UninstallWelcomePage;
    PageText.Left := ScaleX(176);
    PageText.Top := ScaleX(16);
    PageText.Width := ScaleX(301);
    PageText.Height := ScaleX(54);
    PageText.AutoSize := False;
    PageText.Caption := 'Welcome to the My Program uninstall wizard';
    PageText.ShowAccelChar := False;
    PageText.WordWrap := True;
    PageText.Font.Name := 'Verdana';
    PageText.Font.Size := 12;
    PageText.Font.Style := [fsBold];

    PageText := TNewStaticText.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
    PageText.Parent := UninstallWelcomePage;
    PageText.Left := ScaleX(176);
    PageText.Top := ScaleX(76);
    PageText.Width := ScaleX(301);
    PageText.Height := ScaleX(234);
    PageText.AutoSize := False;
    PageText.Caption :=
      'This will uninstall My Program 1.5 from your computer.'#13#10#13#10 +
      'It is recommended that your close all other applications ' +
        'before continuing.'#13#10#13#10 +
      'Click Next to continue, or Cancel to exit Uninstall.';
    PageText.ShowAccelChar := False;
    PageText.WordWrap := True;

    UninstallProgressForm.OuterNotebook.ActivePage := UninstallWelcomePage;

    // Create the first page
    UninstallFirstPage := TNewNotebookPage.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
    UninstallFirstPage.Notebook := UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook;
    UninstallFirstPage.Parent := UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook;
    UninstallFirstPage.Align := alClient;
    
    PageText := TNewStaticText.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
    PageText.Parent := UninstallFirstPage;
    PageText.Top := UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Top;
    PageText.Left := UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Left;
    PageText.Width := UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Width;
    PageText.Height := UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Height;
    PageText.AutoSize := False;
    PageText.ShowAccelChar := False;
    PageText.Caption := 'Press Next to proceeed with uninstallation.';
    
    // Create the second page
    UninstallSecondPage := TNewNotebookPage.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
    UninstallSecondPage.Notebook := UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook;
    UninstallSecondPage.Parent := UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook;
    UninstallSecondPage.Align := alClient;
    
    PageText := TNewStaticText.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
    PageText.Parent := UninstallSecondPage;
    PageText.Top := UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Top;
    PageText.Left := UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Left;
    PageText.Width := UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Width;
    PageText.Height := UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Height;
    PageText.AutoSize := False;
    PageText.ShowAccelChar := False;
    PageText.Caption := 'Press Uninstall to proceeed with uninstallation.';
    
    UninstallNextButton := TNewButton.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
    UninstallNextButton.Parent := UninstallProgressForm;
    UninstallNextButton.Left :=
      UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Left -
      UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Width -
      ScaleX(10);
    UninstallNextButton.Top := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Top;
    UninstallNextButton.Width := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Width;
    UninstallNextButton.Height := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Height;
    UninstallNextButton.OnClick := @UninstallNextButtonClick;
    
    UninstallBackButton := TNewButton.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
    UninstallBackButton.Parent := UninstallProgressForm;
    UninstallBackButton.Left :=
      UninstallNextButton.Left - UninstallNextButton.Width - ScaleX(10);
    UninstallBackButton.Top := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Top;
    UninstallBackButton.Width := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Width;
    UninstallBackButton.Height := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Height;
    UninstallBackButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonBack);
    UninstallBackButton.OnClick := @UninstallBackButtonClick;
    UninstallBackButton.TabOrder := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.TabOrder;
    
    UninstallNextButton.TabOrder := UninstallBackButton.TabOrder + 1;
    
    UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.TabOrder :=
      UninstallNextButton.TabOrder + 1;

    // Run our wizard pages
    UpdateUninstallWizard;
    CancelButtonEnabled := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Enabled
    UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Enabled := True;
    CancelButtonModalResult := UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.ModalResult;
    UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.ModalResult := mrCancel;

    if UninstallProgressForm.ShowModal = mrCancel then Abort;

    // Restore the standard page payout
    UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.Enabled := CancelButtonEnabled;
    UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton.ModalResult := CancelButtonModalResult;

    UninstallProgressForm.PageNameLabel.Caption := PageNameLabel;
    UninstallProgressForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Caption := PageDescriptionLabel;

    UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook.ActivePage :=
      UninstallProgressForm.InstallingPage;
  end;
end;
```

[image: Welcome page]

[image: First page]

[image: Second page]

[image: Uninstall status page]

---

Note that there's no way to use the built-in images from the installer in the uninstaller. In my simple code above, I install the "welcome" page image to the `{app}` and load it from there.

If you want to avoid this, see my answer to the [How keep uninstall files inside uninstaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14847218/850848#38336841)