# Create a checkbox to optionally delete files in a custom page at Inno Setup uninstaller

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation, pascalscript

I created custom pages for an uninstaller using this code: [How to create a OuterNotebook/welcome page in the Inno Setup uninstaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42625626/inno-setup-how-to-create-a-outernotebook-welcome-page-in-the-uninstaller) and I want to create a checkbox that allows me to optionally delete certain files in a custom page (before the uninstallation process). I am trying to use this code:

```pascal
NewCheckBox1 := TNewCheckBox.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
with NewCheckBox1 do
begin
  Parent := UninstallfirstPage;
  Left := NewStaticText1.Left;
  Top := NewStaticText1.Top + NewStaticText1.Height + 8;
  Width := NewStaticText1.Width;
  Height := ScaleY(30);
  Caption := 'Eliminar partidas guardadas';
end;
```

But I do not know how to link this code to the action of removing the additional folder in the uninstallation.

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just test a value of the checkbox in the [`CurUninstallStepChanged` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurUninstallStepChanged) and call [`DelTree` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_deltree) eventually.

```pascal
var
  NewCheckBox1: TNewCheckBox; // a global variable

procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usUninstall then // or usPostUninstall
  begin
    if NewCheckBox1.Checked then
    begin
      Log('Deleting folder');
      if DelTree(ExpandConstant('{userappdata}\My Program'), True, True, True) then
      begin
        Log('Deleted folder');
      end
        else
      begin
        MsgBox('Error deleting folder', mbError, MB_OK);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```