# Inno Setup Script - Uninstall custom page with checkbox options

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation

I need an Inno Setup script which will:

Display a custom form on uninstall that includes:Page title,reasons delete application,and choices with checkboxes and Needed buttons to continue or cancel the uninstall wizard

Comment: and how much are you going to pay per hour?

Comment: Particularly see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42550055/850848